# how to use plotly.js to plot two subplots in the same row sharing xaxis?

Tags: subplot, plotly.js

how to use plotly.js to plot two subplots in the same row sharing xaxis?so when I zoom one chart the other chart will zoom simultaneouly,just as this https://plotly.com/python/facet-plots/,thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this question.For each subplot, just use "matches:'x'",and all the plots will share the one xaxis. Just as code below:

```
layout ={xaxis:{title:'time',},xaxis2:{matches:'x'}}
```